# Using Ubuntu, how do I install DBD::Sybase from CPAN?

Tags: sql-server, perl, sybase, freetds, dbd

Whenever I try to build `DBD::Sybase` to connect to MSSQL I get an error,

```
$ sudo cpanp install DBD::Sybase


Installing DBD::Sybase (1.15)
Running [/usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/cpanp-run-perl /home/ecarroll/.cpanplus/5.14.2/build/DBD-Sybase-1.15/Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]...
Can't find any Sybase libraries in /etc/lib or /etc/lib64 at /home/ecarroll/.cpanplus/5.14.2/build/DBD-Sybase-1.15/Makefile.PL line 155, <IN> line 44.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpanp-run-perl line 11, <IN> line 44.
[ERROR] Could not run '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL': Can't find any Sybase libraries in /etc/lib or /etc/lib64 at /home/ecarroll/.cpanplus/5.14.2/build/DBD-Sybase-1.15/Makefile.PL line 155, <IN> line 44.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpanp-run-perl line 11, <IN> line 44.
 -- cannot continue

[ERROR] Unable to create a new distribution object for 'DBD::Sybase' -- cannot continue

*** Install log written to:
  /home/ecarroll/.cpanplus/install-logs/DBD-Sybase-1.15-1374605483.log

Error installing 'DBD::Sybase'
Problem installing one or more modules
```

I've also gotten this error on other Debian systems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to do that,

- (a) with the freetds that the distro provides
- or, (b) installing the vanilla freetds upstream and building against that.

The second option (b) is always possible, but then your system may have two different versions of freetds.

[The first option can not be done without some hacking and the author will not fix it.](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=34053) He is simply hard headed and wants to fix internal structures to match the OS he uses rather than making it accepting of other configurations.

Internally `DBD::Sybase` expects there to be a directory, and a `$libdir` (a subdirectory with `lib` or `lib64`). The directories `DBD::Sybase` requires to build properly are **not** provided by the Debian package `freetds-dev`; the Debian package installs to `/usr/include` which doesn't have a `lib` or a `lib64` subdirectory. You can get around this by fooling `make` and recreating that structure, first make sure you have `freetds-dev` installed,

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
```

Then link it to create a pseudo-package. On my 64 bit machine, it looks something like this.

```
mkdir /tmp/freetds
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ /tmp/freetds/lib64
ln -s /usr/include /tmp/freetds/include/freetds
```

Now, it should work and you can build `DBD::Sybase` against system libraries.

```
sudo SYBASE=/tmp/freetds cpanp install DBD::Sybase
```

Viola.

Comment: on OS X, you need to fix a stupid bug. edit Makefile.pl and comment out `@libdir = ('dll');` as `/win/` matches "darwin" :(

Answer (score 5):

To install modules for the system perl, you can install the packages from the Ubuntu repositories. While these may be out of date, library dependencies are resolved aoutomatically. In this case, a

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdbd-sybase-perl
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It's not that your idea wouldn't work, but that some perl users don't want a lot of old and outdate distro-provided perl modules just so they can get around having one module they need.

Comment: @EvanCarroll After that link in your answer I understand your actual problem. What a shitty way to react to a bug report. I'll leave my answer here because it shows the “easy” way of resorting to distro packages, even though it is very suboptimal.

Comment: Thanks, and I also appreciate you calling it a shitty way to answer a bug report (that's what it is). It's sad when an issue is plaguing you for 5 years, and each time you try to file the same bug report just to find it already there in the rejected bin. Oh well, self-answering these problems on StackOverflow will make my job easier with Google next time around.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to make the `include` subdirectory, otherwise the second `ln` will fail:

```
mkdir /tmp/freetds/include
```